# How to get current index of root child element regardless of depth

Tags: javascript

I have a `container` div that has a few child `divs`. Each of the child `divs` has unknown structure and content.
There are buttons somewhere that should return current index of only the clicked root child. (without using unique ids)

Example:

```
<div class="conatainer">
    <div class="rootChild">
        <button> Get rootChild index </button>  // should return 0
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someDiv">
            <p> Some text here </p>
            <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someOtherDiv">
            <div class="andAnotherDiv">
                <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know the actual class of the main children that you need to index?

Comment: Nope, but I can simply give it a name and make it unique only for this container's children - that should help, right? If yes you can use the `rootChild` class name as I wrote in the example

Comment: Recursively traverse the parents using base case class is rootChild ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array out of the children and look up from button to closest element with the child class and use `indexOf()` to get index of that child in the array

```js
const cont = document.querySelector('.conatainer'),
  children = Array.from(cont.children);

cont.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('.rootChild button')) {    
    const idx = children.indexOf( e.target.closest('.rootChild'))
    console.log('Index =', idx)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="conatainer">
  <div class="rootChild">
    <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 0
  </div>

  <div class="rootChild">
    <div class="someDiv">
      <p> Some text here </p>
      <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rootChild">
    <div class="someOtherDiv">
      <div class="andAnotherDiv">
        <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Given the other two similar answers, which one do you think is the best? In terms of performance for example?

Comment: Edit: I found your answer to be the best, the other answers log the index a few times rather than once and randomly they would get stuck

Answer (score 1):

This approach should work!

```
// Add event on click for each button inside a .rootChild
document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Find the closest rootChild of the current button
    const thisRoot = this.closest(".rootChild");
    // Get all rootChilds
    const roots = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rootChild"));
    let thisIndex = null;   // Variable where index will be saved
    // Iterate roots
    roots.forEach((root, index) => {
      // If you find the current root, save its index in your variable
      if (root === thisRoot) { thisIndex = index; }
    });
    
    // Do what you want with your index
    console.log(thisIndex);
  });
});
```

### Try it here

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const thisRoot = this.closest(".rootChild");
    const roots = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("rootChild"));
    let thisIndex = null;
    roots.forEach((root, index) => {
      if (root === thisRoot) { thisIndex = index; }
    });
    
    console.log(thisIndex);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="conatainer">
    <div class="rootChild">
        <button>Get rootChild index </button>  // should return 0
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someDiv">
            <p> Some text here </p>
            <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someOtherDiv">
            <div class="andAnotherDiv">
                <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive proposal could not be forgotten!

```
function findIndex(child, count) {
// base case
if (child.classList.contains('rootChild')) {
  return count;
}
count++;
return this.findIndex(child.parentNode, count);
}


document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{console.log(findIndex(e.target.parentNode, 0))});
});
```

Basically, I'm just counting the parents until I reach a parent with class '**rootChild**'

Here's another recursive alternative (a bit more strightforward)

```
function findIndex(child) {
// base case
if (child.classList.contains('rootChild')) {
  return 0;
}
return this.findIndex(child.parentNode) + 1;
}


document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{console.log(findIndex(e.target.parentNode))});
```

### Try it here

```js
function findIndex(child, count) {
// base case
if (child.classList.contains('rootChild')) {
  return count;
}
count++;
return this.findIndex(child.parentNode, count);
}


document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{console.log(findIndex(e.target.parentNode, 0))});
});
```

```html
<div class="conatainer">
    <div class="rootChild">
        <button>Get rootChild index </button>  // should return 0
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someDiv">
            <p> Some text here </p>
            <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rootChild">
        <div class="someOtherDiv">
            <div class="andAnotherDiv">
                <button> Get rootChild index </button> // should return 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit: 1**

One last approach, just to think out of the box :)
There's a property `path` inside the event object which contains all the nodes until the root (starting from the button itself). So, why not just simply iterate this collection?

```
function countByPath(e, targetClass) {
const path = e.path || (e.composedPath && e.composedPath());
return path.findIndex((elm)=> elm.classList.contains(targetClass))-1;
}


document.querySelectorAll(".rootChild button").forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{console.log(countByPath(e, 'rootChild'))});
});
```

Just be aware of the browser support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_event_composedpath

Comment: Haha that's awesome I never thought I'd ever see recursive outside of computer science class in the university. I just wonder if it has a hit on the performance such as higher loading time?